# How do I install Go-ethereum and solidity on Debian10

Tags: go-ethereum, solc, debian

I am using debain on wsl and I want to install ethereum and solidity for blockchain development but I am not able to find an exact way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chain hammer](https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer) uses a geth and solc as dependencies on Debian. You can use borrow parts of the installation script to help you.

- Install Go: https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer/blob/master/scripts/install-go.sh
- Install Geth : https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer/blob/master/scripts/install-geth.sh
- Install Solc: https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer/blob/master/scripts/install-solc.sh

Alternatively, these instructions should work:

- Build from source : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth#build-it-from-source-code
- Build without Go: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth#building-without-a-go-workflow

### Update

To install just Solidity:

```
wget https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/download/v0.5.13/solc-static-linux
chmod 755 solc-static-linux 
sudo mv solc-static-linux /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/solc-static-linux /usr/local/bin/solc
solc --version
```

Comment: ```➜  two43 bash <(curl -Ls https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer/blob/master/scripts/install-geth.sh)
/proc/self/fd/11: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/proc/self/fd/11: line 7: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
➜  two43``` is showing

Comment: shall i first pull it to my repo then delete the line ? @Samuel Dare

Comment: @NeelModi I would just copy the files and paste them and execute them like that

Comment: Also updated answer

Comment: I ended up building it from source

Comment: Now how do I install solc compiler

Comment: Copy and past that script.. chmod +x script.sh . Then run it I.e./script.sh

Comment: updated answer with commands you can run in your terminal to install it (copied from the chainhammer script)